# Trouble calling useStyles in components (Material-UI)

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Currently doing a project with Material-UI's library. Im having issues with styling.

I'm pretty new to ReactJS or just JS in general, and doing this project is my first time I am interacting with it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

I am unable to style my text box like the way example they gave.

this is my code:

```
  class AppBase extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          ...INITIAL_STATE
      };
  }

    classes = useStyles;

  render() {
    return (
      <Container component="main" maxWidth="md">

      <div className={this.classes.root}>
        <TextField required id="standard-required" label="Required" defaultValue="Hello World" />
        <TextField disabled id="standard-disabled" label="Disabled" defaultValue="Hello World" />
        <TextField
          id="standard-password-input"
          label="Password"
          type="password"
          autoComplete="current-password"
        />
        <TextField
          id="standard-read-only-input"
          label="Read Only"
          defaultValue="Hello World"
          InputProps={{
            readOnly: true,
          }}
        />
        <TextField
          id="standard-number"
          label="Number"
          type="number"
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true,
          }}
        />
        <TextField id="standard-search" label="Search field" type="search" />
        <TextField
          id="standard-helperText"
          label="Helper text"
          defaultValue="Default Value"
          helperText="Some important text"
        />
      </div>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

This example I have taken is from: https://codesandbox.io/s/51hrm

I have copied the useStyles exactly at the top, and this is what I get:

[How the code looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4orsh.png)

This is not the only instance where I am facing this issue with calling useStyles in my components.

Calling 'classes = useStyles;' works on some useStyles but not the others, I am really at lost for this.

**Because of the way the other pages has been done, I will not consider using Functions like the example given.**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In the sandbox and in Material-UI, `useStyles` is a function.  It's not shown in your code sample above, but you probably need to call it as a function: `const classes = useStyles();`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're copying the `useStyles` function from the example provide, then it needs to be called as a function.  Right now, you're just assigning the function to the `classes` variable, but never executing the function.  So just change the one line of code as follows:

```
const classes = useStyles();
```

And you will execute the `useStyles` function and assign the result to the `classes` variable.  At that point, you'll be able to use the `classes` constant in your jsx to style the components, like the example:

```
<form className={classes.root} ...></form>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. However, I have tried using const classes = useStyles(); inside my component (class App extends Component {......), but it gives me an error / does not work. Is there anywhere else I can put it? Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

useStyles hook can only be called inside a functional component. You have to change your class component to functional component if you want to use useStyles hook.

I have created a live sandbox for you to play around also: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-bouman-47bek?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

The code below should work fine:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Container, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    background: "linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)",
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: "0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)",
    color: "white",
    height: 48,
    padding: "0 30px"
  }
});

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="md">
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <TextField
          required
          id="standard-required"
          label="Required"
          defaultValue="Hello World"
        />
        <TextField
          disabled
          id="standard-disabled"
          label="Disabled"
          defaultValue="Hello World"
        />
        <TextField
          id="standard-password-input"
          label="Password"
          type="password"
          autoComplete="current-password"
        />
        <TextField
          id="standard-read-only-input"
          label="Read Only"
          defaultValue="Hello World"
          InputProps={{
            readOnly: true
          }}
        />
        <TextField
          id="standard-number"
          label="Number"
          type="number"
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true
          }}
        />
        <TextField id="standard-search" label="Search field" type="search" />
        <TextField
          id="standard-helperText"
          label="Helper text"
          defaultValue="Default Value"
          helperText="Some important text"
        />
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Also I would hight suggest you to start using functional components instead of class components since the functional components are the future of React.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply! Are there no other way around this to use it in class components? Our team has already done quite a bit using this style and might be too much for us novice to change it right now.. Thank you!